# Cursor moving but stuck in the upper-left corner

Tags: boot, unity, nvidia, gnome, mouse

First of all, I want to let you know that I am a complete Ubuntu (and Linux in general) beginner, basically what you can call a newbie.

So last time I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.10 in a dual boot with Windows 10.
I downloaded the .iso and mounted it on a Flash drive using LiLi. Everything went pretty well until I booted on the USB : The mouse seemed to be moving (I could notice that by seeing some buttons getting highlighted as I moved the mouse) but the mouse cursor wouldn't leave the top-left corner of my screen ! 
Fun thing : When I tried to move the mouse to my secondary screen, the cursor just got blocked in the top-left corner... of the secondary screen !

I thought that maybe it was just an issue with the installer, so what I did was that I kept installing the OS and everthing went pretty good. When I booted, I could see the GRUB interface and both Windows and Ubuntu were accessible. Except that the issue was still here.

I've tried several things that I saw on this forum in order to fix this and I did get a pretty bizarre result.
When I installed the nvidia-current package, a lot of stuff changed within my Ubuntu : First, my secondary screen wasn't usable anymore, so I had to deal with only one screen (which didn't really bother me for now). Then, the resolution was really downgraded but it did fix my cursor problem !
The thing is that while solving one problem, it created another.
I was stuck in the login screen, meaning that when I tried to log in, a kind of terminal (I guess ?) appeared in a flash and brought me back to the login screen.

I tried installing Ubuntu Gnome (as I prefer the Gnome environment) but got the same results.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you happen to have an NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: I just want to note my frustration on this.  It's absolutely ridiculous that such a bug is still around.  It's been around for several years at this point and still manages to pop up every once in a while.  I cannot believe it hasn't been fixed.

Comment: I have nvidia and I also had this problem. You haven't specified the model of your pc. If you happen to have dual nvidia/intel graphics card, you can easily fix the login screen problem.